# dompdf create pdf with four columns?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, dompdf

I need to create a pdf with four equal length columns across the page using dompdf.

I have tried  to do this however I can't work out how to correctly set the widths of the columns. It always ends up cutting the last column off.

How can I render a table with a fixed width across the entire PDF page with four equally wide columns?

Comment: No columns... It keeps chopping off the last column on the page. I have tried many different ways of specifying column width but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it looks like all I need to do is set the table width to auto or 100% and let the columns scale across the page automatically without setting their widths.

Answer (score 0):

Dompdf has issues with tables, page breaks and image display..you can see on their own issues website..[Here](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=48)

I use fpdf, and its really simple to use and consistence in design [Check here for simplicity in table display in fpdf](http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/3/)

Comment: The issue I am having isn't across pages. I can't seem to get it to work on one page....